# mejora de un componente hecho con react

Tags: reactjs

estoy creando un input con react, la verdad esta quedando bien, el estilo es lo deseado, pero si al llamar al componente mas de una vez, pueden notar que hay problemas a la hora de mover el `span` que simula ser el `placeholder` se queda quieto y no retoma lo que tiene que hacer, simplemente no reacciona y se queda en su lugar, les dejo el código acá

```
import React from 'react'
import styled, { css } from 'styled-components'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

const ContainerInput = styled.div`
  width: 15rem;
  height: 3rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: .5rem;
  position: relative;
  padding: .5rem;
  border: solid 2px #fff;
`;

const ContainerPlaceholder = styled.span`
  transition: all .3s;
  background-color: #121212;
  padding: .1rem;
  color: #ffffff88;
  ${props => props.move && css`
    transform: translate(0px, -130%);
    font-size: 12px
  `}
`;

const Input = styled.input`
  width: 93%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: transparent;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff
`;

const InputComponent = ({placeholder, type, onChange, value, name}) => {

  const [ userFocus, setUserFocus] = React.useState(false)

  const handleFocus = () => {
    if(String(value).trim() !== "") return 
    setUserFocus(true)
  }

  const handleBlur = () => {
    if(String(value).trim() !== "") return 
    setUserFocus(false)
  }

  return (
    <ContainerInput>
      <ContainerPlaceholder move={userFocus}>
        {placeholder}
      </ContainerPlaceholder>
      <Input name={name} value={value} onChange={onChange} type={type} onFocus={handleFocus} onBlur={handleBlur} />
    </ContainerInput>
  )
}

InputComponent.prototype = {
  placeholder: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  value: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  type: PropTypes.string.isRequired
}

export default InputComponent
```

les faltan algunas mejora al componente, pero recien lo estoy empezando, les dejo un link de  [codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/divine-haze-khepx?file=/src/styles.css) para que puedan verlo en accion

Comment: Hola, pudiste solucionarlo?

Comment: aun no, es un proyecto de componentes para subir a npm

Answer (score 1):

Pude solucionar el problema. Estaba en el state: "value" de App.js. Lo que hice fue inicializar 2 estados para cada input, o sea uno para Usuario y otro para Contraseña.

```
`import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import Input from "./components/imput";

export default function App() {
  //const [value, setValue] = React.useState({ usuario: "", password: "" });
  const [usuario, setUsuario] = React.useState("");
  const [contraseña, setContraseña] = React.useState("");

  const handelInput = (e) => {
    const inputValue = e.target.value;
    if (e.target.name === "usuario") {
      setUsuario(inputValue);
    } else {
      setContraseña(inputValue);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Input
        type="text"
        value={usuario}
        placeholder="usuario"
        name="usuario"
        onChange={handelInput}
      />
      <Input
        type="password"
        value={contraseña}
        placeholder="password"
        name="password"
        onChange={handelInput}
      />
    </div>
  );
}`
```

Te adjunto el link del código para que lo pruebes: https://codesandbox.io/s/spring-rain-960rg?file=/src/App.js